# C++11 auto and function return types

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

I know of the difference between `auto`, `auto&`, `const auto` and `const auto&` (for example in a "for each" loop), but one thing that surprised me is:

```
std::string bla;
const std::string& cf()
{
    return bla;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto s1=cf();
    const std::string& s2=cf();
    s1+="XXX"; // not an error
    s2+="YYY"; //error as expected
}
```

So can somebody tell me when the type of `x` in the expression `auto x = fun();` won't be the same type as the type of the return value of the `fun()`?

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question, even as comments in the code. This prevents future readers from understanding your question as it was at the time you had the problem. I've rolled back your edit to fix this. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The rules for `auto` are the same as for template type deduction:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t); // same as auto
template <typename T>
void g(T& t); // same as auto&
template <typename T>
void h(T&& t); // same as auto&&

std::string sv;
std::string& sl = sv;
std::string const& scl = sv;

f(sv); // deduces T=std::string
f(sl); // deduces T=std::string
f(scl); // deduces T=std::string
f(std::string()); // deduces T=std::string
f(std::move(sv)); // deduces T=std::string

g(sv); // deduces T=std::string, T& becomes std::string&
g(sl); // deduces T=std::string, T& becomes std::string&
g(scl); // deduces T=std::string const, T& becomes std::string const&
g(std::string()); // does not compile
g(std::move(sv)); // does not compile

h(sv); // deduces std::string&, T&& becomes std::string&
h(sl); // deduces std::string&, T&& becomes std::string&
h(scl); // deduces std::string const&, T&& becomes std::string const&
h(std::string()); // deduces std::string, T&& becomes std::string&&
h(std::move(sv)); // deduces std::string, T&& becomes std::string&&
```

In general, if you want a copy, you use `auto`, and if you want a reference you use `auto&&`. `auto&&` preserves the constness of the referene and can also bind to temporaries (extending their lifetime).

Comment: i might be blind or slow :), but that still doesnt explain to me why auto ignored const in my example.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Because that's what the function `f` would deduce too (top-level `const` does not matter in arguments). I added an example with const.

Comment: ouch :( , that is a stupid hole in const system if you ask me... if somebody wrote const in return type they prob had a reason to do that... for all we know they might be giving you a ref to member and they wanna be sure you cant change it(without explicitly casting away the const)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl But since `auto` becomes `std::string`, it will make a local *copy*, so there's really no issue (other than the possible surprise if you're not aware of that). In your code `s1+="XXX"` is changing the local copy, not the object referred to by the result of the function. Note how both `g(scl)` and `h(scl)` deduce references to const: non-top-level const (which is what really matters) is always preserved.

Comment: oh yes, it doesnt remove the const it removes const and &. That makes it less ugly, but still it is unpleasant(if return value is meant to be modified... ). So much for Herb's "use auto everywhere you can"  :)...  Either way tnx for clearing this up? IDK if it is OT but do you know any other problems with auto?  I know of some problems with expression templates but that stuff is too complicated for me anyway.  (http://herbsutter.com/2012/04/03/reader-qa/)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl if you want a nice rule of thumb, I like "use `auto` if you want a copy, and `auto&&` if you want a reference". The latter preserves everything and is what I use by default in, for example, ranged-for loops.

Comment: OK, so am I right to think that X&& will try to bind to X&&, when it fails then to X& when that fails to X, so that is the reason what it "preserves everything"?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Something like that yeah. `X&&` always binds to a reference: an lvalue reference if the input is an lvalue, an rvalue reference if the input is an rvalue.

Comment: OK, I ll edit my answer or you can edit you answer... editing my example to auto&& s2... preserves const and ref :D

Comment: btw stupid question, but why does auto&& preserves const, while auto doesnt ?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Technically, because `void fun(int);` and `void fun(int const);` declare the same function (see http://ideone.com/l6yZu): the caller doesn't care if the function changes its own local argument copy; and the rules are the same as for template type deduction. But it's also what makes sense most of the time. If I want to make a local copy, most of the time I don't want it const. You can always use `auto const` if you really want a const local copy.

Comment: why can't just auto& be used? or const auto& ?

Comment: `auto&` is always an lvalue reference. `const auto&` is always an lvalue reference to const. `auto&&` can be any reference.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't think auto && is good general advice for for loops or similar. I can only think of two use cases: 1) Don't know if receiving rvalue or lvalue, and 2) receiving rvalue, need non-const operations, and don't want to pay for a move that you don't think the compiler will optimize. Otherwise, [const] & cover most situations, with value for small types.

Answer (score 1):

In g++-4.8 there is an enhancement for auto deduction of function return type:

2012-03-21  Jason Merrill

```
Implement return type deduction for normal functions with -std=c++1y.
```

You need the -std=c++1y or -std=gnu++1y flags.

This works:
    auto
    sluggo()
    {
        return 42;
    }

```
int
main()
{
    auto s1 = sluggo();
    s1 += 7;
}
```

The OP question error out only on `+="YYY"` as expected.  You could even declare cf with auto:

```
#include <string>

std::string bla;

const auto&
cf()
{
    return bla;
}


int
main()
{
    auto s1 = cf();
    const std::string& s2 = cf();
    s1 += "XXX"; // not an error
    s2 += "YYY"; // error as expected
}
```

It still errors on `+="YYY"`.

Comment: I dont see how C++1y is related to my question, esp since in C++17?  s1 will still be of type : "std::string"

Comment: I guess it won't help now.  But it looks like function type deduction will be standardized later.  I guess the failure you are getting is "by design".  But other people believe this design is overly restrictive and are working to fix it.