# Forwarding the decltype detection - C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, decltype

I would like to use `decltype` to virtually bind the return type of a method to a type of a variable like that

```
#include <iostream>

decltype(a) foo()                     // my point
{
  return 4.3f;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  auto a = 5.5f;
  std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
  return(0);
}
```

but this code doesn't compile under `g++-4.7.2` on Linux as you can easily guess.

There is a workaround for this ? I know `auto` but this is not what i would like to use ( I do not want to use `auto` for the return type of `foo()`) .

Comment: What do you mean by "_virtually_ binding the return type"? Do mean _virtual_ as in _virtual functions_? I.e. are you talking about some sort of run-time (late) binding?

Comment: @jogojapan "virtual" as "normal people" think of, i mean that `foo` should express the same return type as `a`

Comment: To tie the type of `a` and return type of `foo` together, wouldn't it make sense to introduce a type synonym for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is your goal here? Is it ok to pass the variable in to the function? If not, how is the function expected to know what type to use? If you are ok with passing the variable in to the function, you can use a template:

```
template<typename T>
T foo(T) {
    return 4.3f;
}
```

Now you can call it like

```
std::cout << foo(a) << std::endl;
```

The variable here is only being used to get its type. If you don't want to pass the variable in, then you need to provide the type directly, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
T foo() {
     return 4.3f;
}

std::cout << foo<decltype(a)>() << std::endl;
```

But this is, of course, quite ugly.

Now, if you are willing to use macros, you can simplify this slightly:

```
template<typename T>
T _foo() {
    return 4.3f;
}
#define foo() _foo<decltype(a)>()

std::cout << foo() << endl;
```

but of course this does hard-code the name of the variable that must be in-scope when you call foo().

---

The fundamental issue here is the function cannot implicitly use the type of the variable, as the function is declared first. So if templates are not a good solution, then the only alternative is to declare the type somewhere that both the function and the variable can access it. This can be accomplished with a `typedef`:

```
typedef float atype;

atype foo() {
    return 4.3f;
}

int main() {
    atype a = 5.5f;
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply decide that the return value of `foo()` is considered the authority on the type in question:

```
float foo() {
    return 4.3f;
}

int main() {
    decltype(foo()) a = 5.5f;
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: my point is just using decltype before the declaration of the variable that is used as argument. I'm not asking to stick with the ISO standard, I was thinking that maybe some compiler could support a forwarded decltype with some hack. I have to rethink this, i will take a "no" as the answer, thanks anyway.

Comment: @user1797612: I guess I still don't understand what you're actually asking for. You seem to want the compiler to somehow know what the return type of `foo()` should be, when that information is never given to it anywhere.

Comment: my point is including this decltype in an external header, this implicitly means that the inclusion happens before the variable declaration. that's it.

Comment: @user1797612: Well yes, the function is indeed declared before the variable. Which is why you need some mechanism to pass the type of the variable back to the function. This can be done with templates as illustrated.

Comment: yes, but templates are not that easy to debug and i simply want to avoid them because this keyword does exactly what i want, also templates just allow every type, they are an example of meta-programming and not specifically designed for what i want to do ( which is a much simpler task, in theory ).

Comment: templates do what you want and this keyword doesn't, it just looks like it does, but as you can see, you won't make decltype work for you.

Comment: @LukeB. yes, even before posting this question I have realized that, I was hoping for some workaround or hack; also you can assume that templates are an hack in this case because i have to force a template to work only with my type and not with a generic `T`.

Comment: @user1797612: The fundamental issue here is, if the function is declared before the variable, it cannot implicitly use the variable's type. A third solution that hasn't been offered before is to `typedef` the type you want to use at the top, then use that typedef in both the function definition and the variable declaration. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: @user1797612 I don't see how that's a hack, I really don't understand the usefulness of what you're asking, you need a function with a type that is not known at declaration, but only later, this is the perfect use of templates. It's not a hack because if you somehow supply an invalid type you will get a compiler error. Maybe if you explained what you're trying to do we could offer a different solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could use templates

```
template <typename T>
T foo()
{
    return 4.3f;
}
```

and call it using `foo<float>()`

you can also use `decltype` if `a` is declared before the function, like this:

```
auto a = 5.3f;

decltype(a) foo()
{
   return 4.3f;  
}
```

Comment: For the template-based solution: You could actually say `foo<decltype(a)>()` instead of `foo<float>()`.

Answer (score 1):

With C++1y you will be able to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

auto foo()
{
  return 4.3f;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  auto a = 5.5f;
  std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
  return(0);
}
```

which you can already do with lambda functions.

This is implemented in g++-4.8 with the std=c++1y flag.

I answered here: [C++11 auto and function return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052474/c11-auto-and-function-return-types/12080646#12080646)

Comment: this is just a totally different thing, the `auto` keyword on `foo()` assigns the type based on the return type of `foo()` not on the type of `a` which is what i want.

Comment: @user1797612: But it will act in an almost identical manner to what you're asking for in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after? It should compile:

```
#include <iostream>

const float foo() 
{
  return 4.3f;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  decltype(foo()) a;
  a = foo();
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: nope, my point is about giving more flexibility to the variable, not to the method.