# Why do 'auto' and explicit reference variable declarations behave differently?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, auto

I have something like this:

```
class Bar;

class Foo()
{
 public:
   Foo() : bar(new Bar());
   Bar& GetBar() { return *bar.get(); }
 private:
   std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar;
};

void main()
{
   Foo foo;
   auto bar1 = foo.GetBar();
   auto bar2 = foo.GetBar(); //address of bar2 != address of bar1. why?

   Bar& bar3 = foo.GetBar();
   Bar& bar4 = foo.GetBar(); //address of bar3 == address of bar4.
}
```

It seems the 'auto' variables are copies as I don't get Bars back with the same memory address.
If I explicitly define the variables as Bar references (Bar&) then everything works as I would expect.

I'm compiling in VS2012. What's going on here?

Comment: that confused me also, so some nice ppl solved my problems :) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052474/c11-auto-and-function-return-types

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`auto` works like template argument deduction. `bar1` and `bar2` have types `Bar`, so they are independent copies; `bar3` and `bar4` have type `Bar &` and are references to the same `*foo.bar`.

Comment: but GetBar() returns a Bar& and I would imagine that auto would set the variable to the return type of the function. In any event, I found the explanation here: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html

in the section headed: Auto, References, Pointers and Const.

Kind of weird, that.

Comment: @Aeluned: You can imagine all you want, but the fact is that `auto` works like template argument deduction. When you have `template <typename T> void f(T);` and call `f(foo.getBar());`, you'll deduce `T = Bar`...

Comment: @Aeluned: There are many cases where you would not want that, for example when accessing a field in an object if the accessor returns a constant reference you want to get the value *now*, not a reference to a potentially changing value. The current specification allows you to select if you want a reference by adding `&` as in `auto& bar3 =...`

Answer (score 22):

`auto bar1 = …` always declares a copy. `auto &&bar1` selects the closest possible reference type, which is what you want.

`auto &&` is the *perfect forwarding* idiom.

You can also use other compound types with `auto`, such as `auto const &` or `auto *` if you want to be specific.

Comment: +1, I didn't know `auto` did reference collapsing as well as template type arguments.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Yep, a large proportion of all my variables are declared `auto &&`… it's pretty much my default :)

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
X& getter() {
    static X value;
    return value;
}

print("X:");
X x0 = getter();
auto x0a = getter();
x0.printAddress();
x0a.printAddress();

print("X&:");
X& x1 = getter();
auto& x1a = getter();
x1.printAddress();
x1a.printAddress();

print("const X&:");
const X& x2 = getter();
const auto& x2a = getter();
x2.printAddress();
x2a.printAddress();

print("X&&:");
print("Rvalue can't be bound to lvalue");
X&& x3 = getter();
auto&& x3a = getter();
x3.printAddress();
x3a.printAddress();
```

**Result:**

```
X:
0037F807
0037F7FB
X&:
00D595BA
00D595BA
const X&:
00D595BA
00D595BA
X&&:
Rvalue can't be bound to lvalue
00D595BA
```

**Conclusion:**

`auto` means: "*replace me with type, unless I am `auto&&` then find the most suitable form*".