# Singleton with template

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mutex>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& getInstance() {
        if (instance_ == nullptr){
            std::lock_guard<mutex> guard(mutex_);
            if (instance_ == nullptr) {
                instance_ = new T();
                atexit(&Singleton::destroy);
            }
        }
        return *instance_;
    }
private:
    static void destroy() {
        delete instance_;
        instance_ = nullptr;
    }
    Singleton() {}
    Singleton(const Singleton&) {}
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) {}
    static T* instance_;
    static mutex mutex_;
};
template<typename T>
T* Singleton<T>::instance_ = nullptr;
template<typename T>
mutex Singleton<T>::mutex_;

class Test {
public:
    Test() { 
        i_ = 0;
        cout << "Construct Test" << endl; 
    }
    void setValue(int&& x) {
        i_ = x;
    }
    int getValue() {
        return i_;
    }
private:
    int i_;
};
void main(){
    auto instance1 = Singleton<Test>::getInstance();
    auto instance2 = Singleton<Test>::getInstance();
    instance1.setValue(2);
    cout << instance2.getValue() << endl;
    cout << instance1.getValue() << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Why the type of instance1 and instance2 is Test not Test& ? "Construct Test" print only once, but the result is 0 and 2, instancen1 and instance2 seems two different Test object, the Environment is vs2015

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052474/c11-auto-and-function-return-types

Comment: Also, `void main` is not legal C++ and `#include<stdlib.h>` is deprecated since the first standard.

Comment: Nothing to do with singleton: `auto` wotks as template deduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the type of instance1 and instance2 is Test not Test& ?

Because you would need to use `auto&` in place of `auto`

```
auto& instance1 = Singleton<Test>::getInstance();
auto& instance2 = Singleton<Test>::getInstance();
```

You could verify that you're copying instead of getting a reference to the singleton variable with a copy constructor

```
Test(const Test&) {
    cout << "Copying";
}
```

The rule is

```
int i = 5;
auto a1 = i;    // value
auto & a2 = i;  // reference
```

I'd also pay attention to [Baum mit Augen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555782/singleton-with-template/42555843#comment72245934_42555782)'s comment and avoid using `void main` and `stdlib.h` in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, when i use the                                                     Singleton<Test>& instance1 = Singleton<Test>::getInstance();                   it couldn't work, why?

Comment: @HbShi are you doing it for both `instance1` and `instance2`?

Comment: both or only one all couldn't

Comment: @HbShi I had overlooked that: `Singleton<Test>` is wrong, you're returning a reference to the singleton-managed object. You should do for both: `Test& instance1 = ...; Test& instance2 = ...`